# Algorithm for A/B testing

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I need to develop an A/B testing method for my users. Basically I need to split my users into a number of groups - for example 40% and 60%.
I have around 1,000,00 users and I need to know what would be my best approach. Random numbers are not an option because the users will get different results each time. My second option is to alter my database so each user will have a predefined number (randomly generated). The negative side is that if I get 50 for example, I will always have that number unless I create a new user. I don't mind but I'm not sure that altering the database is a good idea for that purpose.

Are there any other solutions so I can avoid that?

Comment: could you use there user id to set the users in different buckets?

Comment: What kind of number is 1,000,00?

Answer (score 4):

Run a simple algorithm against the primary key. For instance, if you have an integer for user id, separate by even and odd numbers.

Use a mod function if you need more than 2 groups.

Answer (score 2):

Well you are using MySQL so whether it's a good idea or not, it's hard to tell. Altering databases could be costly. Also it could affect performance in the long run if it starts getting bigger. Also you would have to modify your system to include that number in the database for every new user. You have tagged this as a python question. So here is another way of doing it without making any changes to the database. Since you are talking about users you probably have a unique identifier for all of them, let's say e-mail. Instead of email I'll be using uuid's.

```
import hashlib

def calculateab(email):
        maxhash = 16**40
        emailhash = int(hashlib.sha1(email).hexdigest(), 16)
        div = (maxhash/100)-1
        return int(float(emailhash/div))


#A small demo
if __name__ == '__main__':
        import uuid, time, json
        emails = []
        verify = {}
        for i in range(1000000):
                emails.append(str(uuid.uuid4()))
        starttime = time.time()
        for i in emails:
                ab = calculateab(i)
                if ab not in verify:
                        verify[ab] = 1
                else:
                        verify[ab] += 1

        #json for your eye's pleasure
        print json.dumps(verify, indent = 4)
        #if you look at the numbers, you'll see that they are well distributed so 
        #unless you are going to do that every second for all users, it should work fine
        print "total calculation time {0} seconds".format((time.time() - starttime))
```

Not that much to do with python, more of a math solution. You could use md5, sha1 or anything along those lines, as long as it has a fixed length and it's a hex number. The `-1` on the 6-th line is optional - it sets the range from 0 to 99 instead of 1 to 100. You could also modify that to use floats which will give you a greater flexibility.

Comment: That's perfect. Exactly what I needed. No need to do it all at once, just when a user logs in. I'm far from having 1 million users online at once. And either way - it took just over 3 seconds to complete on an quad i7 with 8gb of ram. Thanks!!!

Comment: A real work of art, Alexander! I made a small framework with unit tests based on your work and added your name to the credits: https://github.com/dancrew32/ab Thanks!

Comment: why use a hash function when we run one AB test ? isn't the modulo approach enough ? I agree with using the hash function when we run multiple AB test in parallel though

Answer (score 0):

I would add an auxiliary table with just userId and A/B. You do not change existent table and it is easy to change the percentage per class if you ever need to. It is very little invasive.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the JS one liner:

```
const AB = (str) => parseInt(sha1(str).slice(0, 1), 16) % 2 === 0 ? 'A': 'B';
```

and the result for 10 million random emails:

{ A: 5003530, B: 4996470 }